# Unable to print rownames in ShinyApp

Tags: r, shiny

I am unable to print table rownames in Shiny using the code below:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

myData  <- matrix(
  data=c('13,867','$229,153','30,128','$16.53','98.17%','39.69%'),
  nrow = 6, ncol = 1, dimnames = list(letters[1:6], c("Metrics"))
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    box(dataTableOutput("table"))
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    myData
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And the output I get is shown below. Could someone please point out the mistake?

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VB3pC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add rownames with the `DT` package. `rownames` is an argument of `DT::datatable` which can also be used in `DT::renderDT` via the the `options` parameter.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(DT)

myData  <- matrix(
  data=c('13,867','$229,153','30,128','$16.53','98.17%','39.69%'),
  nrow = 6, ncol = 1, dimnames = list(letters[1:6], c("Metrics"))
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    box(DTOutput("table"))
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderDT({
    myData
  }, options = list(rownames = TRUE))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!